# How to find largest figure in 2d array

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have image with example of matrix with marked cells in it which makes a figures.

[image]

The thing is, that I have to count and find the largest figure in the matrix.

As we can see there is 3 figures each with 3, 19 and 2 black fields.

Ok I understund how could I get if the cell is black or white, but how can I tell that figure is fully counted and which one is the biggest.

Comment: [Floodfill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floodfill)?

Comment: particularly Floodfill with 4 directions.

Comment: Floodfill works just fine.  However, a little more detail may help.  Start at the upper left hand corner.  Scan looking for the first black square.  Floodfill it while flipping the black squares to white.  When the floodfill is done, remember the count.  Start again at the upper left hand corner and look for the first black square.  Repeat and compare the count with the previous pass.  Do this until you can't find a black square.  You now have the largest count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a task for [connected component labeling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)